# SP2010 mixed authentication, windows and forms, both against AD

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to have a mixed mode SharePoint 2010 install where intranet users are authenticated via Windows Authentication, and extranet users are authenticated via forms authentication.

There is an existing solution here, http://www.orbitone.com/en/blog/archive/2010/06/23/sharepoint-2010-mixed-authentication-automatic-login.aspx, but I have one unusual difference. In most cases, the Windows authentication goes against an AD server and the forms authentication goes against an ASP.Net membership database. In my case, they're both going against AD servers. The users who use forms authentication are stored on an extranet AD server, and the users who use Windows authentication are stored on an intranet AD server. The extranet AD server has pass through authenciation set up with the intranet AD server, so SharePoint is always directly connected to the extranet AD server.

Is there a better approach to automatic mixed mode authentication in this case?

Comment: Here are more details. The SharePoint web server is running on a network called DomainA. I want people logging in using FBA to be authenticated against the AD server on DomainA. I want people logging in using Windows Authentication to be authenticated against the AD server on DomainB. There is a one-way trust relationship between DomainA and DomainB.

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing things correctly.  When you have internal users on an external farm, SharePoint will look for an available AD server and send the user in question to AD for verification.  With the one way trust, AD knows to check the trusted domain for the user in question if it does not exist in its own domain.  The whole point of the trust to to avoid calls through the network to your internal domain directly.  So technically the users are being authenticated to the domains as you described.  If its not working, I would bet your trust is not correctly configured.